# Where is the state stored by default if I do not configure a StateBackend?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpoint

In my program I have enabled checkpointing,

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.enableCheckpointing(5000);
```

but I haven't configured any StateBackend.

Where is the checkpointed state stored? Can I somehow inspect this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default state backend keeps the working state on the heaps of the various task managers, and backs that up to the job manager heap. This is the so-called [`MemoryStateBackend`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/state_backends.html#the-memorystatebackend).

There's no API for directly accessing the data stored in the state backend. You can simulate a task manager failure and observe that the state is restored. And you can instead trigger a savepoint if you wish to externalize the state, though there is no tooling for directly inspecting these savepoints.

Comment: There's no API for directly accessing the data stored in the state backend. You can simulate a task manager failure and observe that the state is restored. And you can instead trigger a savepoint if you wish to externalize the state, though there is no tooling for directly inspecting these savepoints.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer, but small addition to the [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51513546/8269828) answer. I can't write comments cause of reputation.

If you use flink version earlier then v1.5 then default state backend will MemoryStateBeckend with asynchronous snapshots set to false. So you will use synchronous saving checkpoints every 5 seconds in your case (your pipeline will block every 5 seconds for saving checkpoint).

To avoid this use explicit constructor:

`env.setStateBackend(new MemoryStateBackend(maxStateSize, true));`

Since flink version v1.5.0 MemoryStateBackend uses asynchronous snapshots by default.

For more information see [flink_v1.4 docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/state/state_backends.html)

Comment: what should be the maxStateSize if i have streaming data which is comming from kafka topic continuously

Comment: You can use default value: 5242880 bytes. But take into account that there is a warning in Flink's docs. WARNING: Increasing the size of this value beyond the default value (5242880) should be done with care. The checkpointed state needs to be send to the JobManager via limited size RPC messages, and there and the JobManager needs to be able to hold all aggregated state in its memory.